# Nuxt3: useRuntimeConfig() var empty after build

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I can't access config variable after `npm run build`. I have following code inside my `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
    ...
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
          chatServer: '',
        }
    },
    ...
```

... so `chatServer` var (according to the nuxt3 convention) is automatically loaded from `.env` file:

```
NUXT_PUBLIC_CHAT_SERVER = http://localhost:6001
```

... and I can access it in my component:

```
const server = useRuntimeConfig().public.chatServer;
```

On `npm run dev` everything is fine.
**However, after `npm run build`, when I run production version of my app (`node .output/server/index.mjs`), that variable is empty**. What am I missing here?

Comment: When I go `npm run preview` everything works but I have such information: "Loading .env. This will not be loaded when running the server in production. ". Then how the heck could I use my env vars in Nuxt3?

Answer (score 1):

So the .env file you have there is only used in development.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-runtime-config#using-the-env-file

When you're actually deploying this later on you should use an appropriate way of injecting these values. The most basic form of doing this would be to just use it in your command where you run the server. I.e.

`NUXT_PUBLIC_CHAT_SERVER=http://localhost:6001 node .output/server/index.mjs`

However the way to do this is dependent on how and where you're deploying your code.

If you're only doing this locally this approach would be fine if you just want to try it out.

If you're deploying this it would be helpful to know where and how you're planning to do that and i'll be happy to help.

One option would be to use e.g. pm2 for deployment and in that case you'd follow these docs for that: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I planned to use PM2 anyway so that's probably the way I'm gonna do it. But it's a pity that Nuxt concepts are so overcomplicated sometimes (my opinion). Miss Laravel... :)

Comment: @stealz I agree with you that this seems overcomplicated. My guess would be that in this case Nuxt do not want to post examples of how you can deploy to production since they don't want the blame if there is a breach in an application using their example. Which is understandable. But as you say, it is really hard to find explanations on how to do this if you're unfamiliar with it.